# Saving/updating data with spring

Tags: java, spring, orm

I get an javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException from the following code:

```
    @Transactional
    public ManagementEmailConfig save(ManagementEmailConfig managementEmailConfig)
    {
        logger.info("Save Management Email Config");
        try
        {
            managementEmailConfig = entityManager.merge(managementEmailConfig);
            entityManager.flush();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            //ERROR: com.xxx.app.dao.kpi.ManagementEmailConfigDAO - 
Not able to save Management Email Config
            //javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.xxx.app.model.configuration.AlertCommunicationAddress with id 1260
            logger.error("Not able to save Management Email Config", e);
            return null;
        }

        return managementEmailConfig;
    }
```

where the model looks like this (shortened version):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the MANAGEMENT_EMAIL_CONFIG database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="MANAGEMENT_EMAIL_CONFIG")
@NamedQuery(name="ManagementEmailConfig.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM ManagementEmailConfig m")
public class ManagementEmailConfig implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="MANAGEMENT_EMAIL_CONFIG_ID")
    private long managementEmailConfigId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AlertCommunicationAddress
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="managementEmailConfig")
    private List<AlertCommunicationAddress> alertCommunicationAddresses;

    public ManagementEmailConfig() {
    }

    public long getManagementEmailConfigId() {
        return this.managementEmailConfigId;
    }

    public void setManagementEmailConfigId(long managementEmailConfigId) {
        this.managementEmailConfigId = managementEmailConfigId;
    }

    public List<AlertCommunicationAddress> getAlertCommunicationAddresses() {
        return this.alertCommunicationAddresses;
    }

    public void setAlertCommunicationAddresses(List<AlertCommunicationAddress> alertCommunicationAddresses) {
        this.alertCommunicationAddresses = alertCommunicationAddresses;
    }

    public AlertCommunicationAddress addAlertCommunicationAddress(AlertCommunicationAddress alertCommunicationAddress) {
        getAlertCommunicationAddresses().add(alertCommunicationAddress);
        alertCommunicationAddress.setManagementEmailConfig(this);

        return alertCommunicationAddress;
    }

    public AlertCommunicationAddress removeAlertCommunicationAddress(AlertCommunicationAddress alertCommunicationAddress) {
        getAlertCommunicationAddresses().remove(alertCommunicationAddress);
        alertCommunicationAddress.setManagementEmailConfig(null);

        return alertCommunicationAddress;
    }


}
```

The use case is that the user provides a new alertCommunicationAddress to an existing ManagementEmailConfig and I want create the alertCommunicationAddress then update the ManagementEmailConfig.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring you've made life really difficult for yourself by not using Spring features

I suggest you do the following:

1. Using [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/), write a repository interface to allow
   you to easily persist your entity:

   public interface ManagementEmailConfigRepository extends JpaRepository { }
2. use it to persist your entity (save is insert if it's not there,
   update if it is)

   @Inject
   private ManagementEmailConfigRepository managementEmailConfigRepository;
   ....
   managementEmailConfigRepository.save(managementEmailConfig);

This gets rid of the following from your code:

1. needing to write a save method at all
2. needing to do a flush
3. no need for try catch type code
4. no need for that named query on your entity
       (you get that for free on your repository)

I'll leave it up to you to decide where you want the @Transactional annotation; it really shouldn't be on your DAO layer but higher up, e.g. your service layer.

Comment: I am looking more for something that makes the old way work, in contrast to something that ends up being a rewrite of 40+ models and classes.